# Calculate Center Of Frustum

Tags: matrix, frustum

If I have a column-major (opengl) Matrix that is the result of multiplying the Projection Matrix by a Model View Matrix. How can I calculate the center point of that matrix? The reason  why I ask is because I only have access to the resulting matrix and i need to find the location of the center of the view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(x,y,z,1)*MVP == (0,0,0,w) -- a point that transforms to the centre of clip space.

That should be simply the last column of MVP^(-1).